# using contain function to add a point to a player class in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift

I have a Player class that I created. The Player class has 2 properties, a playerName and playerPoints.

When I create a player I add it to an array. Later in the program I selected a player and use this function to find out if the player I selected is in the player array (Which I know it will be). This function is nested inside a button function which is where I am getting the sender.tag data from.

```
  if contains(playersArray, { $0.playerName == self.buttonArray[sender.tag].titleLabel!.text }) {


    }
```

I can get this to work, but what I'm not sure how to do is then alter the playerPoints to the Player object that the function results match up to.

So say I have a player Tom. I would search the playerArray for the name Tom. WHen it finds that object with the playerName of Tom, I want to add 1 int to the playerPoints property for the Tom Object.

Comment: Why not store your players in a dictionary, keyed by name?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to increment the playerPoints by 1. Below is example code not checked.

```
if contains(playersArray, { $0.playerName == self.buttonArray[sender.tag].titleLabel!.text }) {
     $0.playerPoints += 1

}
```

### Demo Code

```
var array : Array<test> = []

var test1 = test(playerName: "Tom", playerPoints: 5)

func test1235() {
    array.append(test1)

    if contains(array, test1) {
        test1.playerPoints += 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error back: Anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure

Comment: @icekomo I have added my demo code, check are you doing the same. Because I didn't get any errors.